# Two balls are drawn at random with replacement from a box containing $10$ black and $8$ red balls . Find the probability that both the balls are red

Tags: probability

Two balls are drawn at random with replacement from a box containing $10$ black and $8$ red balls . Find the probability that both the balls are red .

My solution goes like this:

> We have $10$ black and $8$ red balls. The number of ways we can choose $2$ red balls is $\binom{8}{2}$ . The number of ways of choosing $2$ balls is $\binom{18}{2}$ . The required probability is $\frac{\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{18}{2}}$.

However if we do it in this way:

> Considering two events $A$ and $B$ such that $A=$ the event of getting red ball in the 1st draw and $B=$ the event of getting red ball in the 2nd draw. Also, $P(A)$ and $P(B)$  are independent of each other. Now, $P(A)=\frac{8}{18}$ and $P(B)=\frac{8}{18 }$. So, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)=\frac{8^2}{18^2}=\frac{16}{81}$.

So which method is valid. Why is the other one not valid? Where is the problem occuring? I am not getting it.

Comment: A key phrase in the problem is "with replacement". Which of the two solutions properly takes this into account?

Comment: @DanielHast of course the 2nd solution ! But why does the 1st solution is not taking it into account properly ?...

Comment: Because, in the first solution, the numerator (for example) enumerates the number of ways of selecting **two distinct** objects out of $8$.  When sampling with replacement, there is no requirement that the two objects have to be distinct.

Comment: Interestingly, note that if you change the "with" to "without" replacement in the set-up of the problem, $A$ and $B$ become dependent events and so the answer to this (modified) question is: $$P(\text{1st is red and 2nd is red}) = P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B|A) = \frac{8}{18}\frac{7}{18}$$ which is your first answer from above!  [Note: To see this multiply your first answer by $\frac{2!}{2!}$ and note ${8\choose2}\cdot 2! = 8\cdot7$ and ${18\choose2}\cdot 2! = 18\cdot17$.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution corresponds to drawing the balls *without replacement*, which is not what you want.

For example, when you say that

> The number of ways we can choose $2$ red balls is $\binom{8}{2}$

you are not including the case where you draw the same ball twice.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I do get it now....Thank you so much....

Answer (score 0):

A binomial coefficient $\binom n k$ counts the number of ways to draw an *unordered* collection of $k$ items from a larger collection of $n$, *without replacement*. The error is baked into the coefficient itself. Specifically, that coefficient does not count events like drawing the same ball twice.

---

To break down **why** this is the case, let's examine the formula for $\binom n k$:

$$\binom n k = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

This formula can be understood in three pieces:

- $n!$ counts the number of ways to rearrange all of the $n$ items (meaning, put them in an ordered list without repetitions)
- $k!$ counts the number of ways to rearrange the $k$ objects we wish to keep
- $(n-k)!$ counts the number of ways to rearrange the $n-k$ objects we wish to exclude

The intuition of the formula is: first, count all the ways to rearrange all the objects. Then, divide out by the repetitions you don't actually care about; we don't care about the *order* of the objects chosen, and we don't care about the *order* of the objects not chosen.

The main point is that by starting with $n!$, we have built "no repetitions" directly into the formula.